# Insertion sort and linear search at the same time VS Insertion sort and Binary search afterwards?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, search, insertion-sort, array-algorithms

Which is more optimal? (time complexity):

1. Insertion sort and linear search at the same time or
2. Insertion sort and binary search afterwards?

For instance: Insertion sort and linear search at the same time:

```
unsorted integer array = {0...n}
x = element we are looking for
found x at = 0
array enters insertion sort
    if (we find x) //linear search
       found x at = final sorted index of x 
    else
       found x at = -1
 array exits insertion sort
 array is now sorted  
 return found x at
```

Or insertion sort and binary search afterwards:

```
 unsorted integer array = {0...n}
 array enters insertion sort
 array is now sorted
 search x with binary search
 return index we found x at
```

Which is faster?

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to do a **binary search** after the array is sorted?

Comment: I agree with you @Blastfurnace, would make more sense to do a binary sort and search. That is not really the question.

Comment: Then the question changes. Is it better to do insertion sort + search at the same time or insertion sort and bs afterwards?

Comment: Question is somewhat contrived. If you're only going to search once then any kind of sorting is wasteful. Just scan sequentially until you find the one you're after.

Comment: Yeah but I was asking if I want to sort the array and find some element, both operations